# How can my users automatically download the font I use for my website if they don't have it?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

How can users automatically download the font I use for my website if they don't have it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my users automatically download the font I use for my website if they don't have it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566179/how-can-i-make-my-users-automatically-download-the-font-i-use-for-my-website-if)

Answer (score 1):

they don't need to download anything. your fonts , scripts and css files could be stored on your application or you can use a CDN instead.
Google has a nice set of fonts : https://www.google.com/fonts/

here's a simple example:

In your BundleConfig.cs :

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/fonts", yourCDNPathgoeshere));
```

Then you can add this to your layout page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/fonts")
```

Comment: I just edited my answer. I was refering to CDN and wanted to show him where to locate his fonts, css and JS as well

Comment: Thanks for clarification , i just added an example

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend Google fonts. They recently switched to `WOFF2`, which is not supported by iOS (yet).

Your users don't need to download anything, just link the font in your css file.

For example Open Sans, normal thickness is indicated by `font-weight: 400;`.
You add this at the top of your CSS. `WOFF` and `TIFF` are supported almost everywhere. So stick with those.

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url("") format("woff");
```

And then you simply use `font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 12px;` to call the font wherever you want to use it in your css.

*As you can see from `local("Open Sans")` and `local("OpenSans")` the script is also checking if the font is locally available.